# Why set primary interface to `manual` (off) when adding a bridge network?

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I am playing around with KVM and bridge network on a Debian 10 Host

Many tutorials tell to set the `/etc/network/interfaces` to something like this:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual # was dhcp with ip 192.168.188.30 before

# bridge interface for kvm
auto br1
iface br1 inet static
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
address 192.168.188.246
network 192.168.188.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.188.255
gateway 192.168.188.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Why `iface eth0 inet manual` which makes the pc no longer available through `192.168.188.30`?

Gladly I can reach the pc over `192.168.188.246` now.

Even when I set `eth0` back to `iface eth0 inet dhcp` as long as the bridge network is defined I cannot reach the pc over `192.168.188.30` only `192.168.188.246` works.

What if I "apply" `192.168.188.246` to a KVM `VM`. I assume I would lock my self out, since I have no way to reach the host pc - only the `VM` (Did not test, scared, playing with remote sandbox)? If true, how can I be sure to always reach the host pc. Do I add another bridge `br-host` with `192.168.188.xx` which will never be "applied" to a `VM`?

Basically I don't get why the default `eth0` needs to be shut off (manual).

**Edit:**
just to make clear

works for `192.168.188.30`: dhcp

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# no bridge
```

works for `192.168.188.250`

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.188.250
network 192.168.188.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.188.255
gateway 192.168.188.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

# no bridge
```

does only work for `192.168.188.246` not `192.168.188.30`:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp <----- still dhcp

# bridge interface for kvm
auto br1
iface br1 inet static
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
address 192.168.188.246
network 192.168.188.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.188.255
gateway 192.168.188.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

does only work for `192.168.188.246` not `192.168.188.250`:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.188.250
network 192.168.188.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.188.255
gateway 192.168.188.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8


# bridge interface for kvm
auto br1
iface br1 inet static
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
address 192.168.188.246
network 192.168.188.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.188.255
gateway 192.168.188.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

**EDIT 2**

I had a missunderstanding. I thought the host is responsible for getting all the IP adresses which will then applied to the guests. I can just set the IP on the guest and it works. Now everything makes sense. Just had wrong assumption about bridge networks.

Comment: You haven't configured 192.168.188.30 as an address anywhere. Why would you expect it to be used?

Comment: @MichaelHampton even when i keep the default eth0, br1 will "overwrite" it.. see edit

Comment: If you wanted to use DHCP, then why did you configure a static address?

Comment: In other words, why not use DHCP for br1? Currently, if you applied 192.168.188.246 to a VM, the VM would have the same address as the bridge, which would probably make you unable to keep a connection to either.

Comment: I had a missunderstanding. I thought the host is responsible for getting all the IP adresses which will then applied to the guests. I can just set the IP on the guest and it works. Now everything makes sense. Just had wrong assumption about bridge networks.

Comment: consider every guest as own physical computer. From the network perspective these are the same. How can any computer to be "responsible for getting IP addresses" of other computers?